# Android: Does count down timer work in seperate thread or Main UI Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, countdowntimer

I am using `android.os.CountDownTimer`.

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Does `CountDownTimer` methods `onTick()` work in separate thread or Main UI thread ?

Answer (score 0):

As the example (that comes from the documentation) shows, the callbacks (`onTick` and `onFinish`) run on the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in CountDownTimer file ($SDK_FOLDER..\android\os\CountDownTimer.java) that there isn't any explicit reference to any specific Thread.

The counter runs in the SAME Thread of the one in which you where in when "new CountDownTimer(...)" is called.

So if you call "new CountDownTimer(..)" from MainThread/UiThread, then "onTick()" and "onFinish()" runs on that Thread.